# Dynamic change of image of an element in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not completely sure if this is the appropriate place to ask this. If it's not, please pardon me and point me to the place where I should ask it.

Take a look at this page: [lichess](https://en.lichess.org/analysis)

What I'd like to do is:
Depending on which colour I play with (white/black), I'd like like only **my** (white/black respectively) king's image to be changed. So if I'm playing as White, only white king should be affected by this change. Same analogy for when I'm Black. This change would obviously only be seen by myself.

How is this achievable and in what way exactly?

P.S. the website's github (if that helps): github.com/ornicar/lila

Comment: Yes, it's achievable and it's done via event handlers. But, at Stack Overflow, we answer specific coding problems that people have. You'll have to do the research yourself and come back with code that you've tried and a specific question about that code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give sort of an outline, and some code. This can be achieved based on what color the user picks. If you have this stored in a variable (ie. Javascript `var color = white;`), it can really help. First, make sure your image's src empty, when you hard code it. Then, after the user picks his color, you can change the image. Example below.

```
<img src="" alt="player" />
<script>
function initImage(color) {
    var imgsrc = document.getElementById("imgplayer").src = color + ".jpg/.png/etc.";
}
</script>
```